# Link extends to space outside of image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Edit: figured it out, explanation at the bottom

I have a gallery of thumbnail images that link to the bigger image. I am using bootstrap 3.

Some images don't fill up the entire column and there is varying amount of space between each image(but bootstrap aligns them correctly). For some reason, the extra space is "clickable". I want the only the image to be clickable. How do I do this?

The relevant part of the code starts at `<div class="row">`.

```
<body>
{% include "gallery_navbar.html" %}
<div class="tab-content">
  {% for pane_name, reddit_posts in reddit_posts_by_pane.items %}
    {% if pane_name == "food"  %}
      <div role="tabpanel" id="{{ pane_name }}" class="tab-pane active">
    {% else %}
      <div role="tabpanel" id="{{ pane_name }}" class="tab-pane">
    {% endif %}
    {% if reddit_posts %}
      <div class="row">
        {% for reddit_post in reddit_posts %}
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <a data-rel="prettyPhoto[asd]" title="Image {{ reddit_post.rank }}" href="{{ reddit_post.submitted_link }}" style="display:block; height:100%; width:100%;">
              <img class="thumbnail center-block" data-src="{{ reddit_post.submitted_link }}">
            </a>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div><!--end row-->
    {% endif %}
  </div><!-- end tab-pane-->
  {% endfor %}
</div><!--end tab-content-->
```

edit: The extra horizontal link space went away with `display: inline-block` but the bottom padding/margin still links to the link. I can remove the bottom padding with `margin-bottom=0px` but I haven't figured out a way to add the bottom padding back.

edit2: I couldn't change the row div tag, not even by adding another class like "row-padded" making it:

```
 <div class="row row-padded">
```

with css:
     `.row-padded{ margin-bottom:30px}`

So I just went the roundabout way by adding a div tag on top of the link.

Comment: you're going to need to post the CSS as well at least.  Also, what you've tried and why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, change **html** like below

```
<div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 text-center"><!--add class text-center-->

            <a data-rel="" title="" href="" style="display: inline-block;"> <!-- change style attribute -->
              <img class="thumbnail align-center" src="" style="margin-bottom:0px;"><!-- remove class center-block and add style attribute    -->
            </a>
          </div>
</div>
```

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/qb7xnfbd/

Comment: thanks, `display: inline-block;` fixed the horizontal link "space". Is there any chance you know how to fix the extra space on the bottom without removing the space with `style="margin-bottom:0px;`? I've been playing around with padding-bottom and margin-bottom on div class row but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 4):

The `img` tag displays as inline text, sitting on the text baseline, which has space below it for any character descenders and underlines.

Making the `img` display as a block fixes the issue.

Try:

```
a > img:only-child {
  display: block;
}
```

which makes images that are the only child of a parent `a` display as a block.

A nice description of why this happens can be found here: http://doctype.com/anchor-tag-containing-only-img-extends-below-bottom-image

Answer (score 0):

You can also use display:contents on the `<a>`: it will completely disappear (along with other styling such as margin) and you can style the image directly as if there was no `<a>` around.

But there is a caveat with accessibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#display_contents